# Magento 2: Unregistered User does not get proper error message while signing in

Tags: magento2, login

If the user is not yet applied for the registration and he tries directly trying to log in on our website it shows the message like "**This account is not confirmed**". Instead of displaying this message to users who are not yet applied for the registration we've to display an error message like Your username or password is incorrect.

Comment: is this a core functionality or you have used some of custom modules ?

Comment: @Oscprofessionals I thought it should be done by custom module.